# Miscellaneous Operator inquestion:this does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, search-box

According to [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), there is an `inquestion:this` operator to search for answers within the question itself. This is useful for questions with answers that span multiple pages.

However, it seems that this is currently malfunctioning and I was unable to get it to work.

Example post used: *[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)*

Incorrect results are shown for `inquestion:this fail` when on the question itself.

If the question ID is used instead, [`inquestion:11227809 fail`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A11227809%20fail&mixed=0) - the expected results are displayed.

---

This issue was detected while development of my "[Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011)" userscript, which builds advanced search queries.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth: Repro'd (Latest Chrome / Win 10)

Comment: By the way, miscellaneous tip: `is:question` can be shortened to `is:q`, and `is:answer` can be shortened to `is:a`.

Comment: By "malfunctioning" do you mean that "this" isn't being substituted with the question id from `Referer` (sic)? It seems like that's just been turned off. `user:me` is working fine, though; perhaps this fell through their test-cases and they forgot to support it?

Comment: @Samuel Still working fine for me. Is there an update related to the retag?

Comment: @41686d6564 Did you go to the example question, then type this in the search bar? `inquestion:this fail`

Comment: @Samuel [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmBjF.png). Using Chrome on Win10.

Comment: Weird, might be a mod-only bug now...

Comment: I am able to repro this on Main, but not on Meta, @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 6):

This feature depends on the users' browser sending correct Referer headers that contain a question id. Our server expects to receive the Referer in the format, `Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/question/123`, but does not in some cases.

The cases where we don’t send the `Referer` header are:

- You haven’t opted into cookies
- You belong to a Team and we can’t send Referer headers
- Your browser is preventing the Referer header from being sent because of privacy concerns (not currently the default for any major browser)

These limitations can hinder the functionality of our feature. To address this issue, we have made modifications to our process to ensure that all users can utilize the feature without any hindrances.

Previously, we were relying on the `Referrer` in the request header. However, we have now decided to replace `inquestion:this` with `inquestion:<questionId>` before sending it to the backend. We believe this will fix this issue once and for all.

Answer (score 5):

This is now fixed for public users, but not for teams. We're thinking about how to best address this balanced with security. For now, I'm calling this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as it both:

- Hasn't been used in `Teams` (we may just call it unsupported) and
- Isn't nearly as useful there, with traditionally far smaller question/answer counts

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out. We are restructuring our index and in doing so accidentally broke this functionality. It has now been fixed.

Comment: Is the fix in prod yet? The issue is still there

Comment: @SamuelLiew yes, it should be. Odd.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue.

Comment: @SamuelLiew you're correct, and I've reproduced. We're working on a fix now, realistically could be 2-3 weeks.