# Search option `inquestion:this` not working (again)

Tags: bug, search

This is a regression of [Miscellaneous Operator inquestion:this does not work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370497/4751173) which was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I'm member of two Teams, but it doesn't matter if I select All or Public in the dropdown:

[image]

The `inquestion:this` operator seems to be ignored altogether:

[image]

It *might* have something to do with an improperly working redirect. I tried to reproduce the behaviour while not being logged in (in a private browser window). The first time, I had to do a captcha and the search didn't work properly like above; the second time, it did work as expected.